# how to save multiple files with selected columns using lappy in r

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have a dataframe with 98790 rows and 284 columns

```
 otu1    otu2     35-T80-FDA.x  35-T80-FDA.y  33-T26-FDA.x   33-T26-FDA.y
1: OTU_1  OTU_10  3.807355      5.403722     3.972693        3.787
2: OTU_1 OTU_100 -1.618910      0.000000     0.000000        5.687
3: OTU_1 OTU_101  0.000000      0.000000     0.000000        4.9898
```

I have paired column names.

> 35-T80-FDA.x and 35-T80-FDA.y
>
> 33-T26-FDA.x and 33-T26-FDA.y and so on

So In the output, I need 1 and 2 columns and the consequent paired columns in a separate files. the desire output will be:

file1:

```
otu1    otu2     33-T26-FDA.x  33-T26-FDA.y  
1: OTU_1  OTU_10  3.807355      5.403722            
2: OTU_1 OTU_100 -1.618910      0.000000             
3: OTU_1 OTU_101  0.000000      0.000000
```

file2:

```
otu1    otu2     35-T80-FDA.x  35-T80-FDA.y  
1: OTU_1  OTU_10  3.807355      5.403722            
2: OTU_1 OTU_100 -1.618910      0.000000             
3: OTU_1 OTU_101  0.000000      0.000000
```

I tried using lapply function as follows but do not know how to get the paired columns in the output file

```
lapply(names(res_merge_2)[1:281],function(nm) {
  d1 <- res_merge_2[, c(names(res_merge_2)[1:2], nm)]
   colnames(d1)[5]="nlr"
  fwrite(d1,  file = paste0("",nm, ".csv"))})
str(res_merge)
res_merge_2
```

kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split.default` based on the common pattern in the names, bind every part to the first two columns and use `fwrite` to write the data.

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- df[,-c(1:2)]

lapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\..*", "", names(df1))), function(x) 
      fwrite(cbind(df[,1:2],x), paste0(sub("\\..*", "", names(x[,1])), ".csv")))
```

Comment: I did not get any saved files. Why is it

Comment: @MSM Sorry, a small typo. Updated the answer, can you check now?

Comment: I did not get any error. But there are no output files saved in the folder. the format is dataframe. is there any problem?

Comment: It works for me. Please check files in your working directory which can be found by `getwd()`

Comment: I change my dataframe into datatable. and It worked now

Comment: ok...the rownames with colon and `fwrite` used made me believe it is `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in base R by cueing off the unique chunks in the names of the paired columns (and the two columns you want to recycle across all the output files). So, here, you use `grep` and `gsub` to create a vector of those unique stumps from the colnames of `res_merge_2`, then iterate a simple column-selecting-and-csv-writing function over it.

```
lapply(unique(gsub("-FDA.*", "", grep("-FDA.*", names(res_merge_2), value = TRUE))), function(x) {

    write.csv(res_merge_2[,c(grep("otu", names(res_merge_2), value = TRUE), grep(x, names(res_merge_2), value = TRUE))],
              sprintf("%s.csv", x))

})
```

This isn't a bad place to use a `for` loop instead, though, e.g.:

```
for (x in unique(gsub("-FDA.*", "", grep("-FDA.*", names(res_merge_2), value = TRUE)))) {

    write.csv(res_merge_2[,c(grep("otu", names(res_merge_2), value = TRUE), grep(x, names(res_merge_2), value = TRUE))],
              sprintf("%s.csv", x))

}
```

Both of those worked for me on this toy data set:

```
res_merge_2 <- structure(list(otu1 = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", 
"dog", "dog", "dog", "dog"), otu2 = c("cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", 
"cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat", "cat"), `X32-T26-FDA.x` = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), `X32-T26-FDA.y` = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), `X15-X3Q-FDA.x` = c(-0.0391614774317114, 
-0.749042584495182, -1.35322520345808, -0.542635541523875, 0.554157309246222, 
-0.022582818348649, -1.02251842826834, 1.30695316220872, 0.733483858951273, 
0.495620995563405), `X15-X3Q-FDA.y` = c(0.097683395164639, -1.31072727972662, 
-0.324722669182535, -0.194820429986227, 1.13036969830475, -0.376850316761238, 
-1.89704006462136, -0.11021797586389, -0.243968444535775, 1.12909359192043
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```